# Explanation for the TEXTUREACCESSes?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Can someone explain the differences between the three different textureaccesses and what they are useful for? I have different textures for various purposes and I want to set them to the correct type for the best results.

```
SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC
SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING
SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the wiki:

SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC -> changes rarely, not lockable

SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING -> changes frequently, lockable

SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET -> can be used as a render target

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTexture

Comment: I've already read those descriptions, but I'm having a hard time understanding the TARGET one is useful for.

Comment: @TakingItCasual To render into it and then do post processing operations on it. Or maybe you want to render a mirror, which you would do by rendering a second camera into the mirror texture.